# Get wrong formatted date in Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am making a API request but when i retrieve `created_at` then i get `2019-10-09T11:07:08.000000Z` but in database it is `2019-10-09 11:07:08`. How can i solve this issue? I don't want to use date formatting because i already have proper date format in my database. I just want what i have in database. Look at my database: https://prnt.sc/piljms

**API Controller:**

```
 public function singleGallery($id)
    {
        $gallery = Gallery::findOrFail($id);
        return new GalleryResource($gallery);
    }
```

**Gallery Resource:**

```
    return [
        'gallery_id' => $this->id,
        'created_date' => $this->created_at,
        'modified_date' => $this->updated_at
    ]
```

Comment: What's wrong with `2019-10-09T11:07:08.000000Z`? What are you expecting?

Comment: @fox91 in database it is `2019-10-09 11:07:08`

Comment: I saw your edit, can you clarify? Do you expect a date in MySQL (or another DB) format?

Comment: I want date as it is in database stored. In database it is `2019-10-09 11:07:08` then why it is showing `2019-10-09T11:07:08.000000Z` ?

Comment: Probably is the default settings in Laravel, you need to format the date as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Using php's **date** and **strtotime** function you can format date as per your choice.

```
'created_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->created_at))
```

I have formatted created_at in Year/month/date but you can do different formatting like d/m/Y for day/month/Year

If you would like to go Laravel way then you have to use [Carbon](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon) library.

Comment: I don't want to format it like you give here. My database have `2019-10-09 11:07:08` but why it is showing `2019-10-09T11:07:08.000000Z`? I just want what i have in database.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud When you hit any query, laravel at first run its own different modules/middlewares under the hood. In this case, laravel is using the date format = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u'; internally before outputting. So, you need to format in your own way.

Answer (score 0):

Go with this:

```
return [
    'gallery_id' => $this->id,
    'created_date' => $this->created_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'modified_date' => $this->updated_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
]
```

Comment: What the reason you use `format()` as i already have that format in my database? Take a look into my database: https://prnt.sc/piljms

Comment: It really depends on DB tecnology, but probably your date isn't saved formatted in that way by your DB, only display it in that way.
Do you read the date from your database as _"string"_ or as PHP DateTime (or similar) object? Maybe Laravel do it for you...
Can you post the result of `var_dump($this->created_at);`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use DateTimeInterface;
    
    class Notification extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        
        protected $fillable = [
            'id',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
        ];
        
        protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
        {
            return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }
    }
    ?>
```